# Android respective javax.print.PrintServiceLookup class or implementation

Tags: java, android, printing

For a desktop java app I can use javax.print.PrintServiceLookup to get available printers. Is there any relative class for android ?

Comment: There is no native printing capability in the Android SDK; you will need to look at third-party libraries.

Comment: If I use wifimanager or ConnectivityManager I would have better luck? Just to discover the 1st available printer

Comment: There is no native printing capability in the Android SDK. When you find a third-party printing library for Android (and I presume there are some), the authors of that library will give you advice regarding printer discovery using that library.

Comment: Do you know any third-party printing library to suggest because I didn't manage to find any?

Comment: Sorry, I have never gone looking for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Android 4.4 / Kitkat the package [android.print](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/package-summary.html) is available representing a different API and usually implemented by custom printer services provided by printer manufacturers.

However, if you'd like to bypass the service/component Android provides and communicate with an IPP printer directly, you can do so by using the [ipp-client library](https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-client-kotlin). The main difference is that you'd than have to provide a printable document (in a pdl format supported by the printer itself, hopefully pdf). This document is than submitted to printer together with print options you might want to set e.g. like duplex or color.